# Divide into 2 groups in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, abtest

For AB test purposes, I want to make in Tableau 2 groups of the users that participated in the test.
I have their PINS as identifiers.
How can I divide them into 2 groups?

Thanks

Comment: you have not shared anything about what language, technology, frameworks ...etc that you're using ... read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I agree that more information is needed here, however, for the purpose of splitting a field into categories, a set or a calculated field can be used. Please provide a little more detail, sample data, and expected outcome. I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [grouping](https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/grouping?product=tableau_desktop%2Btableau_prep&version=tableau_desktop_2019_1%2Btableau_prep_2019_1_2&topic=visual_analytics), [sets](https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/creating-sets?product=tableau_desktop%2Btableau_prep&version=tableau_desktop_2019_1%2Btableau_prep_2019_1_2&topic=visual_analytics) or [calculations](https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/logic-calculations?product=all&version=tableau_desktop_2019_1&topic=calculations) features in Tableau.  Each of them can separate data into separate groups.